# Family or families

Tags: grammar

I see people posted stuff on facebook telling their friends and family to stay safe. My question is shouldnt it be friends and families. Not friends and family.? or are they indicating one family as of their own family? what if the person is married and has kids? wouldnt that be 2 families?

Comment: Family is family. People are either your relations or they are not. "Friends and family" is the usual construction. "Friends and families" just sounds odd.

Comment: I suggest that you look up family in a good dictionary, like this one: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/family. Check **all** of the definitions. And **please** do a bit of research before asking questions.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Ho, ho, ho! Your majesty is pleased to jest.

Comment: You wouldn't say about yourself "I have 2 families", would you?

Comment: @NahMah Your question is insightful, however unintentionally. If one had more than one family, the plural might be appropriate; and if the FB post addresses multiple people, the plural _would_ be technically correct. However, _friends and family_ is an idiom. Do people always use perfect grammar in your first language in their ordinary speech?

Comment: Well   one could see a use such as *How many families are you part of?* but the only thing that comes to mind is European royalty.

Comment: @AlanC - There are other places where the plural could be used, too. For example, if I'm talking about my parents and siblings plus my wife's parents and siblings, I might say, "Our families get together every year in July." In that case, I'm drawing attention to the fact that it's actually two families getting together – my family, and my wife's family.

Answer (score 5):

A family is a group noun and in the expression "friends and family" the speaker is referring to their own family (meaning the people related to them). Depending on exact context or intent, that could be only people more closely related to them or may include more distant relations.

"Family" can occur in the plural, but that would be when you are referring to more than one group of people where each group consists of members related to each other.

> My three brothers and I are taking our families on a trip this summer

In this case, each brother has a family (usually wife and kids).

Answer (score 0):

As @P. E. Dant commented, "friends and family" has become idiomatic, largely (in my view) to the advertising of cellphone carrier service plans. So it is natural to say, whether grammatical or not.

Otherwise, your question could have two meanings:

> 1) **friends and family** - your friends and *your* family

In this case there is only one family (yours) so "family" singular is correct.

> 2) **friends and (their) families** - your friends and *their* families.

Now "families" plural is OK, but it doesn't make a lot of sense. Because:
1) Your family is not included
2) It would likely be an indeterminate number of people. And if you leave out "their", it could include all families in the world.

Comment: I think you need full sentence examples for 1 and 2 to make the distinction clearer. I can't really see where "friends and families" would be interpreted as "your friends and their families"

Comment: @eques As I wrote, it doesn't make a lot of sense, but I made my best estimation. Anyway I agree that more context is needed. The question is likely to be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

> Family

is used to describe a group of people who are closely related, usually genetically.
The singular also has the underlying meaning of having the speaker's affection

> I consider them family.
>
> My family includes my uncles, aunties and cousins.

When used this way, "family" can mean several generations

> a family gathering

and a "family gathering" may consist of several individual families.

> Each of my cousins brought their families to the family gathering.

"Families" (plural) here means the individual units whereas "family" (singular) refers to the overarching connection of everyone.