# possessive ('s) used in the word "family"

Tags: double-possessives

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> He's a friend of my family.
>   He's a friend of my family's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Family or families](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104445/family-or-families)

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, both have been used by authors (after checking on [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friend%20of%20my%20family%2C%20friend%20of%20my%20family%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20my%20family%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriend%20of%20my%20family%20%27s%3B%2Cc0)). In fact, there is another variation as well - `my family friend.`

Personally, I may prefer the first one because the preposition *'of'* already takes care of the *possession.* And thus, the apostrophe there looks redundant.

Comment: Also very common: *a friend of **the** family*

Comment: “…a friend of my family” and “…a friend of my family’s” are clearly synonymous.
“my family friend” is merely similar.

I suggest none of those is as common as “… a friend of *the* family…”; prolly not even put together.

One *might* prefer the first but never because the preposition “already takes care of the possession” or makes the apostrophe look redundant; that simply can’t be.